# Tire-pressure on Toyota Vitz 2012

Tags: toyota, tire-pressure, vitz

I have a Toyota Vitz from 2012 and i want to know what the air pressure is for its tires, the only information the car has are in this picture, and all the manuals i search for are in japanese. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same car that was sold as Toyota Yaris in Finland. I used to have a 2011 model of that car, with the same 1NR-FE engine. The tires were, if I recall correctly, 185/60R15.

According to this source: https://www.puretyre.co.uk/search-results-for-toyota-Yaris-06-11-185/60R15

...the 185/60R15 tires have a recommended pressure of 2.3 bar front and 2.2 bar rear when not fully loaded. I would modify the recommendations and put 2.3 bar in the rear as well, in preparation of higher than usual loads.

This source: http://www.tyre-pressures.com/bycar/manu_toyota/7796/8660

...on the other hand says 2.2 bar front and 2.2 bar rear.

I don't have now access for the user's manual of the car, but both of these suggestions sound about right. I used to put about that pressure to my tires when I had the car.

Before properly inflating/deflating your tires to the correct pressure, please check the tire size! The sidewall should say something like 185/60R15. If it doesn't, you have a different tire size and none of my recommendations apply!

If you have the car and a camera, you could take a picture of your tire sidewalls and augment the question, so that potential readers of this site have an understanding of your tire size. Proper inflation pressure depends not only on car model, but also the tire size.

**Edit:** I found the owner's manual: https://www.toyota.com/t3Portal/document/om-s/OM52B50U/pdf/OM52B50U.pdf and it says for normal conditions 2.2 bar front and rear, and for hauling ass, 2.4 bar front and rear. Nice! The car manufacturer has anticipated high speed driving in the user's manual. This is for 185/60R15 tire size, so be sure to check you have the same size!